# SecureStore deletes my token each time I refresh the expo client

Tags: javascript, react-native, authentication, expo

I have problem retrieving my authentication token from SecureStore while I develop my app in the expo client.

I’m trying to implement this authentication flow from react navigation using secureStore instead of Async storage: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/4.x/auth-flow.html

Currently, when I login my token is stored in SecureStore. I know this because I can then use it for authorising my requests.

My problem is when the expo client I'm developing my app in refreshes, the token seems to disappear so I have to sign in again.

Does the expo client app refreshing clear the token from secure store or is there a bug in my code that stops me from retrieving the token when I am opening my app again:

```
useEffect(() => {
_bootstrapAsync = async () => {
  const token = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('token')
  navigation.navigate(token ? 'App' : 'Auth');

};
_bootstrapAsync();
```

}, [])

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping a try-catch block around both `getItemAsync` and `setItemAsync` and see whether you're getting any errors as a start.

There's also a chance that you're using an old import syntax, make sure you're using `import * as SecureStore from "expo-secure-store"`, this will cause an error like `undefined is not an object` so the data was never saved.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by adding a `useEffect` that would check if there is a Token, if there was a token i set it and if not i removed it.